# Google Drive, auto delete files older than 7 days in specific folder

Tags: file, google-drive-api, directory, backup

I'm using Google drive to store my daily made backup from my linux machine.
But i need a script that auto delete's the files in a specific folder after 7 days.
So that there are 7 backups in the folder.

The file that get's backup is called world-$(date +%d-%m-%Y).tar.gz
it replaces the %d %m and %Y with the day month and year it created the backup.
so let's say it created one today it would be called world-14-09-2018.tar.gz
it get's stored inside a folder called backups

Is there any way to have it auto delete the files so not store the inside the trash but delete's them completely after 7 days.

I'm not really familair with those kind of scripts. So if anyone could help me that would be really awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/) for Google Drive. There are official client libraries for several languages, listed [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/)

Authenticate your account via OAuth2. Depending on the client library you use, there are different tools to do this. I'm most familiar with the Python SDK, and I use Google's [oauth2client](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.tools.html). The run_flow() command is a simple way to get an OAuth2 refresh token that you can then use to authenticate API calls. [Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)'s the full documentation for authenticating to Google Drive via OAuth2.

Once you're authenticated, you can call the [files list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) endpoint. By default, this will list all files in your my drive. You can limit the search to just those files so you don't have to iterate through all your files each time using a [search query](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters). If you have more backups than can fit on a single page (it doesn't seem like it, esp. with the max pageSize of 1000), you will have to [paginate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42980094/how-to-loop-over-nextpagetoken-using-googledrives-python-quickstart) your calls.

You can then filter your results by either the filename (as you indicated) or by the createdTime parameter in files.list in your code. Make sure to include createdTime in your fields, by setting the fields parameter to a comma-separated list of parameters, ie "files(id,createdTime,name,mimeType)" or, simply, "*" to get every field. Get a list of all files older than 7 days, then call [files.delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete). You can then run this script on a cron job every night, however you want to deploy it.

Alternatively, you could use the unofficial [Drive](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive) command line tool, which will take care of a lot of this for you.