# Google API, name io is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-drive-api

so, by following the google drive API documentation i was trying to create a program that would look in all my saved spreadsheets on google driver and download them.

the problem is i keep getting name 'io' is not defined

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
            file_id = item['id']
            request = service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id,
                                                        mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
            fh = io.BytesIO()
            downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
            done = False
            while done is False:
                status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
                print ("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

so... what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

- You want to download Google Spreadsheet as XLSX file using google-api-python-client with python.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

I thought that from your error message, it is found that the authorization process was done and `token.pickle` was created and `service.files().list()` worked. In this answer, I suppose this. If you cannot create `token.pickle` file yet, please check [the Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) again.

#### Modification points:

- About the error of `name 'io' is not defined`, please add `import io` to your script. By this, this error message can be removed.

But in your script, there are more modification points. So please check the following points.

- I think that after `import io` was added, an error of `name 'MediaIoBaseDownload' is not defined` occurs. So also please add `from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload`.
- When `import io` and `from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload` were added, I think that an error of `insufficient authentication scopes` occurs. So please modify the scope from `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly` to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`.

  - At this time, please delete `token.pickle` file and please reauthorize the scopes by running the script. By this, the new scope is reflected. Please be careful this.
- If there are the files except for Google Spreadsheet in your Google Drive, I think that an error occurs at `service.files().export_media()`. When you want to retrieve only Google Spreadsheet, you can use the search query. In your case, `q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'"` can be used.
- In your script, `fh = io.BytesIO()` is used. In this case, the file is downloaded as the export. But the downloaded file is not created in your PC. If you want to create the downloaded files to your PC, for example, please modify `fh = io.BytesIO()` to `fh = io.FileIO(item['name'] + '.xlsx', mode='wb')`.

When above modification points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

**Before you run the script, please delete the file of `token.pickle`.** By this, when you run the script, the authorization process is run and when the authorization is done, the new scope is reflected to the access token and refresh token.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

import io  # Added
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload  # Added

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']  # Modified

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)", q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'").execute()  # Modified
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
            file_id = item['id']
            request = service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id,
                                                        mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
            # fh = io.BytesIO()
            fh = io.FileIO(item['name'] + '.xlsx', mode='wb')  # If you want to create the downloaded file to your PC, please use this instead of "fh = io.BytesIO()".
            downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
            done = False
            while done is False:
                status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
                print ("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Note:

- If you want to download the files more than 10, please modify `pageSize=10`. The max value is 1000. If you want to download the files more than 1000, it is required to modify the script using `pageToken`. Please be careful this.

  - In this case, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42980094/7108653) might be useful.
- If an error occurs when you run the modified script, please confirm the value of `items` of `items = results.get('files', [])`. When `items` is no values, it means that `service.files().list()` doesn't return the file list.

#### References:

- [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)
- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.