# Why am I getting an empty array when I run a requests.get and a json a second time in the same code set?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm running a program to pull information from Google Maps API. The API only loads 20 responses (max 60) at a time so I have to send an initial request, and then a second and third request to get all the data. My issues is that the second request seems to work (I'm getting  returned), but when I try to parse it using json, I'm getting an empty array. The code works in the first iteration, but doesn't work the second time.

First iteration:

```
response1 = requests.get(url1)
print(response1)
results1 = response1.json()['results']
print(results1)
jj1 = json.loads(response1.text)
print(jj1)
```

Second iteration:

```
if 'next_page_token' in jj1:
  next_page_token1 = jj1['next_page_token']
  url2 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key='+str(api_key)+'&pagetoken='+str(next_page_token1)
  print(url2)

  response2 = requests.get(url2)
  print(response2)
  **results2** = response2.json()['results'] *results2 is []
  print(results2)
  jj2 = json.loads(response2.text)
  print(jj2)
```

Comment: This seems to be a very specific issue with API implementation/usage and not python related.This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/43028879/2695448

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by adding a pause in the execution of the code. There are 3 Google Maps API requests in my code. If they process without a pause, I get an error message. Once I added the following module and code, the code worked.

`enter code here`
import time
time.sleep(2)